# Using a Bootstrap theme - Adding jQuery external library

Tags: jquery

I'm using a theme downloaded from the internet, This theme using Bootstrap and jQuery and everything was working fine till I tried to add an external jQuery library to make advanced HTML select lists.

I tried to use many but let's take this one for example:
https://select2.github.io/

I'm trying to normally include the CSS and JS files into my code

```
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

and start activating and using the script but it dose not look like it's working at all.

Here is what my default header includes looks like:

```
    <link href="css/flags/famfamfam-flags.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/themecss/revolution-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link href="css/themecss/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">     
    <link href="css/themecss/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/colors/color-default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

And here is what my foorter includes looks like:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.smartmenus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.stellar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/SmoothScroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.lightbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/jquery.montage.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/helper-plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/helper-plugins/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/helper-plugins/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/helper-plugins/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/revolutionjs/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/revolutionjs/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.tooltipster.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/TimeCircles.js"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/tweetie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.nouislider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/application.js"></script>
```

Wherever I try to put the new CSS include and JS include in the header and footer it never want to work, Also when I want to activate it by jQuery code like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').select2();
</script>
```

Please I need your help to make these external libraries work on these ready built themes. I really don't know what is the problem.

I'm ready to provide any other information related to my theme or structure.

Thanks guys in advance :)

Comment: If you are in local you must specify protocol like so: `href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com`

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: @Bluety - I tried locally and forking it and no difference.

Comment: @j08691 - Yes I checked and it gives nothing ....

Comment: You call select2 after jQuery ?

Comment: @Bluety .. Yes after the jQuery include line in the footer, I include the library JS then call the code directly after.

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/select2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('select').select2();
</script>

and sure the CSS including in the header

Comment: Can you put your code in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Which parts you need me to put  jsfiddle.net ??

Comment: jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/h8av0658/1

Comment: Still not working inside my theme

Comment: Thank you @Bluety .. It's fixed down in the second answer .. Thank you for trying yo help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your includes like this::

```
<link href="css/flags/famfamfam-flags.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/themecss/revolution-slider.css" rel="stylesheet">    
<link href="css/themecss/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">     
<link href="css/themecss/animate.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="css/colors/color-default.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:400,100,200,300,500,600,700,800,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.2/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />



<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0-rc.2/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.smartmenus.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.stellar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/SmoothScroll.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.lightbox.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/jquery.montage.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/jquery.carouFredSel-6.2.1-packed.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/helper-plugins/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/helper-plugins/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/helper-plugins/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/helper-plugins/jquery.ba-throttle-debounce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/revolutionjs/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/revolutionjs/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.easypiechart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.tooltipster.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;sensor=false&amp;.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/themejs/TimeCircles.js"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/tweetie.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/jquery.nouislider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/themejs/application.js"></script>
```

And don't forget to wait till the dom is ready to call the function like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() { //wait till dom is ready
    $('select').select2(); //then call code
  });
</script>
```

If testing locally, make sure you put `http:` or `https:` in front of each **external** link as I have done above. Protocolless links (ones with that part left off) will not work when run locally. You should be getting an error in the console like the one below as you have it now:

[image]

**Also, one of the libraries you are using is overwriting `$` so that it is no longer an alias for `jQuery`, see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/**

A quick fix would be to use the longer `jQuery` instead of the `$` alias:

```
jQuery(function() { 
    jQuery('select').select2();
});
```

If it were me though, Id try to safeguard the other library from overwriting `$` since I (and most others) are pretty used to `$` being equal to `jQuery`, something like this would really annoy me.

Comment: I'm doing the includes exactly as you mentioned and I tried to call code as you mentioned and still its not doing anything to my select lists.

Comment: It's included good because I checked this many times but the problem that it's not affecting anything

Comment: Load the page in your browser, right click on the page and click "view source", find the link to `select2.min.js`, right click it and click "open in new tab". Is the file loaded or do you get a 404 error?

Comment: In the fiddle you posted, you dont actually call `select2()` Also, with fiddles, use the `External Resources` tab on the left to add libraries, raather than posting them in the js field, see http://jsfiddle.net/DelightedDoD/h8av0658/1/

Comment: Well yeah, the first one doesnt work because you never call `select2()`, the second one works because you do

Comment: Yes second one I called - still not working on the theme

Comment: Can you load you files to a live site so we can see them?

Comment: Ok this will take a while .. I will upload and feedback

Comment: Okay, in the meantime, just for grins, try this: `jQuery(function() {  jQuery('select').select2();   });`

Comment: Worked Perfectly!
Thanks you so much for this. Can you clarify why please and how to avoid?

Comment: Im glad it worked, so you understand why this is happening: One of the libraries you are using is overwriting `$` so that it is no longer an alias for `jQuery`, see http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/

Comment: Thank you so much @DelightedD0D ... I'm trying to make repetition up but it's not allowing me to do it .. You very helpful Thanks a lot .. At least update the answer please it's very good one

Comment: NP, If it were me though, Id try to safeguard the other library from overwriting $ since I (and most others) are pretty used to `$` being equal to `jQuery`, something like this would really annoy me. But if you're using a theme and won't be adding much code yourself it might not be an issue for you

Comment: Yes I can also try to consider this .. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need wait the dom is ready like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('select').select2();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Yes I did Bluety and still not affecting my select lists

Comment: Is it possible that maybe another code is affecting my select lists and this new one I'm adding is not able to override the original one?